# Systemd: start a unit after another unit REALLY starts

Tags: nfs, glusterfs, systemd

In my particular case I want to start `remote-fs` unit after all `glusterfs` completely starts.

My systemd files:

`glusterfs` target:

```
node04:/usr/lib/systemd/system # cat glusterfsd.service 
[Unit]
Description=GlusterFS brick processes (stopping only)
After=network.target glusterd.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "/bin/killall --wait glusterfsd || /bin/true"
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c "/bin/killall -HUP glusterfsd || /bin/true"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`remote-fs` target:

```
node04:/usr/lib/systemd/system # cat remote-fs.target 
[Unit]
Description=Remote File Systems
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Requires=glusterfsd.service
After=glusterfsd.service remote-fs-pre.target
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

OK, all Gluster daemons start successful and I want to mount Gluster filesystem via NFS, but Gluster's NFS share gets ready not immediately after `glusterfs.service` started, but a few seconds later, so usually `remote-fs` is unable to mount it even regarding `Requires` and `After` directives.

Let's see the log:

```
Apr 14 16:16:22 node04 systemd[1]: Started GlusterFS, a clustered file-system server.
Apr 14 16:16:22 node04 systemd[1]: Starting GlusterFS brick processes (stopping only)...
Apr 14 16:16:22 node04 systemd[1]: Starting Network is Online.
Apr 14 16:16:22 node04 systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Apr 14 16:16:22 node04 systemd[1]: Mounting /stor...
```

Here everything is OK, remote filesystem (/stor) seems to be mount after glusterfs started, as it meant to be according to unit files...  But the next lines are:

```
//...skipped.....
Apr 14 16:16:22 node04 systemd[1]: Started GlusterFS brick processes (stopping only).
```

What? GlusterFS got ready only for this moment! And then we see:

```
//...skipped.....
Apr 14 16:16:23 node04 mount[2960]: mount.nfs: mounting node04:/stor failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory
Apr 14 16:16:23 node04 systemd[1]: stor.mount mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Apr 14 16:16:23 node04 systemd[1]: Failed to mount /stor.
Apr 14 16:16:23 node04 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Remote File Systems.
Apr 14 16:16:23 node04 systemd[1]: Unit stor.mount entered failed state.
```

Mount failed because NFS server was not ready when systemd attempted to mount the storage.

Due to non-deterministic nature of systemd boot process, sometimes (approx. 1 of 10 boots) mounting this filesystem on boot succeeds.

If onboot mount was unsuccessful, I can login to the server and manually mount the /stor directory, so Gluster's NFS service seems to work fine.

So how to start `remote-fs` after `glusterfsd`, i.e. after `Started GlusterFS brick processes` line appears in the log?

`remote-fs` seems to be one of the very last targets, so I can't get it start after another "workaround" target which is in fact not required by `remote-fs`.

Comment: Can you add a `ExecStartPre=<command>` property to the Unit section of `glusterfsd.service` that executes a command that will block until glusterfs is ready? That may prevent the the `glusterfsd.service` from indicating success and activating the `remotefs.target`.

Comment: I'm really confused by your `glusterfsd.service` unit file. It doesn't seem to actually start any services, and in fact *kills* any `glusterfsd` processes. Do you have any other gluster-related unit files?

Comment: Can you also show the `stor.mount` unit?

Answer (score 5):

You can analyze systemd boot sequence by following command. View the output file by using a SVG supporting web browser.

```
systemd-analyze plot > test.svg
```

That plotting will provide you last boot's timing statistics, which will provide you more clarified point of view to problem.

I solved my NFS mounting problem by adding `mount` commands in to `/etc/rc.local`. However I'm not sure, will it work with glusterd integration, worth a try for a quick fix. In order to make systemd run rc.local you should satisfy following condition:

```
# grep Condition /usr/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested by others; I'm not sure whether it's actually a dependency on 'glusterfsd', instead of a general delay in something else, for example a DNS lookup that needs to succeed for it to be able to resolve 'node4' and succesfully mount the NFS share.

We've run into this delay because most of our setups use a local validating resolver, which needs to be available before other services that depend on DNS can start successfully.

The solution to this was to have an 'ExecStartPre' script that basically tests for the availability of the specific dependencies over and over, until it succeeds (exit 0) or times out trying (exit 1).

Make sure you customise outside of the main systemd lib directory, if you can. Changing the package files will mean they'll likely be overwritten on the next update that comes along.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add this to `remote-fs` target:

```
[Unit]
...
ConditionPathExists=/stor
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some polling could help. This is independent of systemd. For example I use `mysql -e ';'` in a loop before doing something useful with mysql.